# Is it possible to automatically generate an amazon lex chatbot based on user parameter input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, generator, code-generation, amazon-lex

Is it possible to generate an amazon lex bot based on user's input. I want to create a piece of software, which takes into the input of certain paramters, which would consequentially generate amazon lex files and then upload and publish to the AWS ? I have started researching ways into doing such, and I can see to some extent I can create amazon lex bot files and import them manually, but are there any easier approaches which automates the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach to generating a Lex bot would be using [AWS Sam](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) to upload [JSON files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/import-export-format.html) describing the desired Lex features. You may need to add additional instructions for permissions through the [aws command-line utility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html).

To start, you might want to build out the shared/common features in Lex, export them, and then modify the JSON files for automation.

Using a deployment process like this also makes it possible to deploy automatic updates in the future.

Comment: Can I also generate webhooks for my lex bot through AWS Sam

Comment: You can use CloudFormation to deploy your Lambda functions and use another Lambda function to invoke the Lex Model Building API to set the Lambda as either the DiaglogCodeHook or FulfillmentCodeHook on the individual Intents within your Lex bot.